# Attach 110(2012) from SQL Server 2014 Instance to a (110) SQL Server 2012 INSTANCE

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database on a 2014 instance with compatibility set to 110. When I try to attach it to a SQL Server 2012 instance it says cannot attach version 782 to 706.

I thought I could attach a compatibility of 110 from a SQL Server 2014 to a SQL Server 2012 since in the 2014 the compatibility to 110

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Old article but still valid https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/04/26/whats-the-difference-between-database-version-and-database-compatibility-level/

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. Compatibility mode makes no difference here. You simply can't go back to 2012 from 2014 via backup/restore or detach/attach.

Your options are limited to either generating scripts to recreate the schema and objects or using a third party tool. Red gate have one but I've never used it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot attach a 2014 database to a 2012 instance, compatibility level doesn't matter, just the version matters. Attach and restore are not backwards compatible. If you need to move the database to 2012, you'll need to script out the objects and transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [SQL Azure migration wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) and select SQL server in source and destination